# Slam Toolbox Map saving automation

Tags: ros

fisrt of all I need the info that is about the overwriting or re-saving the map with serialize or deserialize process while using lifelong mapping mode in slamoolbox with melodic version.
I have seacrhed github, ros answers, robotics stack exc. sites and also I read slide is about slamtoolbox but I couldn't get the exact answer about it. I need this answer because I have a dynamic, huge  map and I need to overwrite existing map while I am using lifelong mapping mode. Is it possible to so so or do I need to use serialize/desrialize tool in rqt config? OR If it is already exist where and how to use?
When I shoot a glance the environment there is a possiblity of saving the new map with wrong datas (like slamtoolbox is confusing when I start the robot with similar corridor and puts things in this corridor even if the things dont belong this corridor etc.)
Is there any suggestion to overcome this issue and to automate map saving with less (closes to zero  error I prefer) error?
If I am not obvious I can give more details.
Have a nice day!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serialization / saving features are just ROS Services, you can call that service whenever you like with whatever filename you'd like to save it to. You don't need to use the Rviz tool - the Rviz tool just uses service calls under the hood to tell SLAM Toolbox to perform the serialization of the state.

You can write a pretty simple script in Python or even in Bash to save on some fixed frequency or based on events from your application software.

Comment: Yes, I saw in the codes (https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox/blob/melodic-devel/slam_toolbox/src/map_saver.cpp#L57C1-L58C1) I thought I can actually use the smilar thing to achieve my purpose. I just wonder is there any point that I am missing.Then I will use kinda code that you mentioned.